# Android Studio: Gradle Sync failed

Tags: android-studio, gradle

I have a problem with Gradle

```
Gradle sync failed: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
        Could not determine artifacts for com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.1
        Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.aar'.
        Could not HEAD 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/25.1.1/appcompat-v7-25.1.1.aar'.
        Connect to maven.google.com:443 [maven.google.com/216.58.205.163] failed: Connection timed out: connect
        Connection timed out: connect
        Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (38m 44s 794ms)
```

I have not used Android Studio for three months, so I think the problem is related maybe to some not uploaded configuration files. Or what else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to `https://maven.google.com`, you have a timeout.

- Check your internet connection
- Check your firewall / proxy / gateway
- Just type `https://maven.google.com` in your browser and make sure it's working